# PHP - load a require file only if any of the following fodernames are in the url

Tags: php

I would like PHP to require a file if any of the following folder names exist in the URL:

I am using the following command and it works:

```
<?php if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'one')) {{require_once 'data/header-activity.php';};} elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'two')) {{require_once 'data/header-activity.php';};} elseif (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'three')) {{require_once 'data/header-activity.php';};} else {{require_once 'data/header-city.php';};} ?>
```

I would like to use the above but instead of having to use else if, I would like to use OR

so if the url has in it any of the following folder names: /one/ or /two/ or /three then load the file header-activity.php else if the url does not have the folder names above then load the file header-city.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an array with the names you want like so

```
$folders=array('one','two','three');
$found=false;
```

and use something like :

```
foreach($folders as $v){
  if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$v)){
    $found=true; break;
  }
}
```

notice the `break;`it will prevent the loop from continuing once it found what it was looking for.

and finally include the file depending on the results

```
if($found){
  require_once 'data/header-activity.php';
}else{
  require_once 'data/header-city.php';
}
```

---

All together it would be something like:

```
$folders=array('one','two','three');
$found=false;
foreach($folders as $v){
  if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$v)){
    $found=true; break;
  }
}
if($found){
  require_once 'data/header-activity.php';
}else{
  require_once 'data/header-city.php';
}
```